# Calling on a Range in VBA

Tags: vba

What am I doing wrong with my code below? I am trying to name a range of data that is highlighted in excel and be able to call it in the VBA code and paste it, transpose it, etc. somewhere else but it keeps giving me an error.

```
Sub routine()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Cells(10, "D").Select
rng.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

I also notice that when type "ActiveCell." and hit space i get a drop down of options. however the case isn't true when i type "Cells(1,1)." and space. Why is that? Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: You are pasting without first copying?

Comment: Is your error "Data on the Clipboard is not the same size and shape .. "?

Comment: From you sample data a simple `ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Copy Cells(10, "D")` would do the copy and paste. To `Transpose` would be something like Ahmad's code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: after reading the comments:
Here is a simpler way to copy a range of cells, then pasting special (values) to somewhere else. I obtained this code my recording a macro entirely.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1:C3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(10,"D").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

---

If you meant to copy the D10 range to whatever activecell is, then Change

```
Cells(10, "D").Select
```

to

```
Cells(10, "D").copy
```

You also need to specify what do you want to SPECIALLY PASTE  (values? format?)
So your full code should be like

```
Sub routine()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

    Cells(10, "D").Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False   'This will only paste values

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thank you so much for your help. But the code isnt working. After defining that this block of data is the range, I would like to go to another cell and paste it there.

Comment: Please tell me exactly what you want to accomplish in normal terms. What is it that you want to copy and where do you want to paste it, and do you want to only paste values/format or else?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, yes so I want to select a range of specified data, say Range("A1:C3"), name it rng, and then go to cell(5,"F") and paste the values of the entire block. Hope I am a little more clearer. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @gabriel just use `Range("A1:C3").Copy Cells(5, "F")`. Ahmad, the `Selects` are redundant

Comment: Hi brett I know I can use the copy ---> desintation in one line. But I would like to able to define the range and go to another cell and paste values. How do I do that?