# Setting Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling on a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319813/calling-on-a-range-in-vba)

I am trying this code for this task.  I noticed that when I don't set the range to a name, the code works but when I name the block of data I am working as a "rng" the code gives me an error. What am I doing wrong in this code? Thank you!

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Copy
Cells(1, "d").Select

rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Does it fail on `Cells(1, "d").Select`? I would expect you to write `Cells(1, 4).Select`. I don't think it takes a string like that

Comment: @Brad It does take a column name as a string.

Comment: @GSerg Interesting...I guess it does. cool

Answer (score 2):

`Range.Copy` does not return the copied range. It copies the range to the clipboard and returns a `Boolean` value.

And when you paste, you call `PasteSpecial` on the destination area on the sheet, not on the "copied" range.

```
Dim source as Range, target as Range

Set source = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
Set target = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "d")

source.Copy
target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Also note that `Operation` does not accept `xlPasteValues`, you probably meant `xlPasteSpecialOperationNone`.